# Can not read parquet file from minio S3 with Pyspark

Tags: pyspark, parquet, minio

I have very simple Pyspark job to read parquet file from Minio S3 bucket.
Minio+Jupyter Notebooks are running in docker-compose

```
 spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
 
spark.sparkContext._jsc\
     .hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.access.key", "***********")
spark.sparkContext._jsc\
     .hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.secret.key", "***********")
spark.sparkContext._jsc\
      .hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.endpoint", "http://127.0.0.1:9000")
spark.sparkContext._jsc\
      .hadoopConfiguration().set("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem")
spark.sparkContext._jsc\
      .hadoopConfiguration().set("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.path.style.access", "true")
spark.sparkContext._jsc\
      .hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.multipart.size", "104857600")


measures = spark.read.parquet("s3a://measures/6200703043294113.parquet")
```

while running getting error:

*Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o153.parquet.
: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException*

From the other side - I can read the same parquet file locally from file system.

Am I missing something?